# phpMyAdmin maximum upload size not changed

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to import a large zipped SQL file (5MB) to phpMyAdmin. It shows: `Max: 2,048KiB` I have increased all limits in php.ini but it does not increase.

I am using OpenLiteSpeed and CyberPanel with default settings.

Is it possible to add the zipped SQL to a folder on the server and import from there in phpMyAdmin? Will 2 MB limit still exist in that case?

Comment: Try to import from mysql console

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try in 30 minutes

Comment: Hi, the mysql console worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking about a feature called the [UploadDir](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir), which lets you define a folder where phpMyAdmin can import files that you upload through some other means. Setting `$cfg['UploadDir']='/some/path/` causes files in that folder to automatically show up in the phpMyAdmin import page.

As far as changing the PHP settings, you can [refer to the documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-cannot-upload-big-dump-files-memory-http-or-timeout-problems); ensure that you've changed each of these and then restarted the webserver:

- `max_execution_time`
- `upload_max_filesize`
- `memory_limit`
- `post_max_size`

Comment: Hi, the mysql console worked fine.